# Probability calculation decision trees model, machine learning in R

Tags: r, package, rpart

I am totally stucked in one place. What I want to do is to calculate probability for decision trees model for train_data with which I have worked. It seems like I have to activate library called rpart, but for some reason it just does not work for me...

> library(rpart)
>
> Error in value[3L] :    Package ‘rpart’ version 4.1.11 cannot
>   be unloaded:  Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace ‘rpart’ is
>   imported by ‘ipred’ so cannot be unloaded

This is the error I get after I want to use rpart. I have tried to choose diferent CRAN mirror, did not help. I use R version 3.4.3, which is the newest one.

Comment: The error is implying that you should be able to proceed without loading rpart since it is already imported by another package.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "ipred" prevents to load "rpart" for some reason.
Try `detach("package:ipred", unload=TRUE)` and then try to load "rpart" again.
If it works, try to load "ipred" afterwards.

Comment: Yeah it did work, but somehow the "caret" package and "rpart" are not in very good cooperation. Now "rpart" works fine, but "caret" does not work...

library(caret)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘lubridate’

I have tried to uninstall package "caret", than install it again, did not helped.

Comment: @manduJ. It seems `caret` depends on `lubridate`, which may be missing. Try `install.packages("lubridate")`?

Comment: Thanks, somehow when I tried install package lubridate, it did not work, so I shut down R, tried it again and it has worked.